# What algorithm to find percentage of closeness of multiple points in a range

Tags: algorithm, math

in a range of numbers from 0 to 1, i have defined 3 points: point A at 0, point B at 0.5 and point C at 1

what algorithm would be used to find the "weights" or percentages of closeness of a value in the range to each of the 3 points

for example, the value 0.25 in this range might have a weight of 0.5 towards A, 0.5 towards B and 0 towards C and the value 0.6 may have a weight of 0.1 towards A, 0.7 towards B and 0.2 towards C

someone gave me a -1, if you think this is a silly question please tell me why it is stupid i honestly want to know

Comment: Not the down-voter, but I am a close-voter.  This is not a "stupid" or "silly" question, but it's also not a good question.  There are many ways to measure distance, and many ways to convert those measures into weights, and you just haven't provided enough info to narrow down the options.  As Mooing Duck noted, "do we therefore choose any algorithm that looks like this?"  That makes it an ambiguous question and ambiguity is not the basis of a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't defined exactly what weights are. Do we get to therefore choose any algorithm that looks vaguely like this?

The obvious thing to do would be to find the distances, invert them (1/x) and then normalize those (finding values that sum to 1 but have the same ratios).

- A value of 0.25  for A=0.0, B=0.5, C=1.0 would have distances of 0.25, 0.25, 0.75. Inverting those gives 4, 4, 1.3 (which sum to 9.3) and then normalizing those  results in (4/9.3=) 0.428, (4/9.3=) 0.428 and (1.3/9.3=) 0.142.
- For a value of 0.6, the distances would be 0.6, 0.1, and 0,4. Inverting those gives 1.66, 10, and 2.5, and normalizing those results in 0.113, 0.706, and 0.177.

Does this match what you're looking for?  One problem here is that if the value given matches A, B, or C exactly, you get a division by zero in the middle, as that one gets an infinite weight, but the end result is trivial to calculate: 100% for that value, the rest get 0%.